# Problem expressing that because a given linear functional is unbounded, that a norm inequality cannot hold.

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my problem:

Let $X$ be a Banach space with norm $\|x\|$. Let $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-zero, unbounded linear functional. Prove that $\|x\|_\phi :=\|x\|+|\phi(x)|$ defines a different norm on X.

---

So I basically have this one done, I have just come into one problem expressing something.

We know that $(X,\|x\|)$ is a Banach space, and by definition it is trivial that $\|x\|\leq\|x\|_\phi, \forall x\in X$. Assume that $\|x\|$ and $\|x\|_\phi$ are equivalent. Then by assumption there exists a finite $K$ such that $\|x\|_\phi\leq K\|x\|, \forall x\in X$.

... **And here is where I am having trouble expressing what I am thinking**. I know that since $\phi$ is not bounded, that there **does not exist** a finite $C$ such that $|\phi(x)|\leq C\|x\|, \forall x\in X$, and therefore no $K$ exists which holds the equivalence inequality.

Any advice how to properly express this idea?

Comment: On an infinite dimensional space it is not the case that all norms are equivalent.  Does the problem specifically call for proving equivalence?  As you have written it it only asks for "different."  I agree with your intuition that it is not equivalent.

Comment: No, the problem calls for proving that they are not equivalent. @JasonKnapp

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi$ is unbounded, you have a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $|\phi(x_n)|/\|x_n\|\to+\infty$. Thus
$$\frac{\|x_n\|_{\phi}}{\|x_n\|}=\frac{\|x_n\|+|\phi(x_n)|}{\|x_n\|}= 1+\frac{|\phi(x_n)|}{\|x_n\|}\to+\infty.$$

Comment: Could you please explain a bit how you came up with this? I am thinking that you are modifying the definition of bounded linear functional, to do something like this: $|\phi(x_n)|\leq C\|x_n\| \implies {|\phi(x_n|\over \|x_n\|}\leq C$ and as $\phi$ is unbounded, ${|\phi(x_n|\over \|x_n\|}\to \infty$ ? @Milly

Comment: For any $M>0$ it must exist $x_1$ such that $|\phi(x_1)|>M\|x_1\|$, otherwise we would have $|\phi(y)|\leq M\|y\|$ for any $y$ (i.e. $\phi$ bounded). Thus I can choose a sequence $M_n\to +\infty$, and for each $M_n$ I choose $x_n$ such that $\|\phi(x_n)\|>M_n\|x_n\|$. Hence $|\phi(x_n)|/\|x_n\|\geq M_n\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great way of expressing what I was thinking about. :) @Milly